# Maximum number of skill points you can have in Torchlight 2?

Tags: torchlight-2

In Torchlight 2, you can get skill points from level and fame. I am not sure if there are any other means to get skill points.

What is the total of number of skill points you can obtain from the various sources?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The level cap is 100 and the fame cap is 33. You get 100 skill points from the levelling process and another 33 from levelling up your fame level so I expect the maximum number of skill points available is 133 assuming there are no quests which grant skill points directly and no other mitigating circumstance.

It is worth noting that it takes 100 skill points to completely fill out one tree, so at maximum level you will be able to fill out around one and a half skill trees.

Furthermore, there was a calculator for Torchlight II (link removed as calculator no longer exists at that site), which performs the same actions as you'd expect from a skill calculator and lets you work out your character build without committing any changes in game.

<sup>[Source](http://forums.runicgames.com/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=33550#p308432) | [Source](http://www.runicgamesfansite.com/torchlight-2-general/5455-total-number-skill-point-available.html)</sup>

Comment: This answer is wrong. I downvoted it. Because there are only 33 fame levels. http://forums.runicgames.com/viewtopic.php?t=36060

Comment: Strange, well updated my answer, I figured somebody from RGF would have been correct but oh well

Comment: You can get the 1 skill point from your starter skill back for free when you reach the enclave and talk to the respec guy. Has to be done before your 3rd point spent.

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 1):

You have 100 skill points from levels. For the first skill (that is automatically spent), you can go do a skill respec and take it off for free and use it on another skill.

Each skill tree has 7 spells and 3 passives. that makes 105 points to max out spells and 150 in total to max out an entire tree with all 3 passive skills.

To clarify, so far I have completed the campaign doing every quest, and none gave skill points, so it should be a max skills points of 133.

Answer (score 1):

The max number of skill points you can allocate to a specific character is 132.

Answer (score 0):

The max level in game is 100, so that's 99 skill points you can allocate (you start at level 1 with 1 point in a skill).  I don't know if there is a maximum fame level, so I can't say how many fame SP you can expect to get.

Also, expect there to be mods to increase or remove the levelcap eventually.  Whether these are to personal taste is another question.

Comment: You can remove that one preallocated skillpoint if you like.